# NSDocument XML read Issue

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, macos, nsdocument

I am working on a NSDocument based Mac app. Which imports .xml file. It's working fine for some xml files but for few having issues.

**Issue is read() is modifying the data when we import file, i need to keep the original data as it is.
what do i need to do to make sure i get original xml data in the read()?**

I am using below function to read the file

```
override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {
    var error:NSError? = nil
    var xmlDocument1:XMLDocument? = XMLDocument()
    do{
        xmlDocument1 = try XMLDocument(data: data, options: XMLNode.Options(rawValue: XMLNode.Options.RawValue(Int(XMLNode.Options.nodePreserveWhitespace.rawValue))))
    }catch let err as NSError{
        error = err
    }
    if error != nil {
        throw error!
    }
}
```

and i parse xmlDocument1 to read and get all the xml information.

Issue: Doing this way swift is modifying the document, as mentioned below.

**Example 1:**

Original:

```
<iws:attr-option name="1 - Poor" /> 
<iws:attr-option name="2 - Needs Improvement" />
```

Data getting from Read(), notice the closing tags added automatically

```
<iws:attr-option name="1 - Poor"></iws:attr-option>
<iws:attr-option name="2 - Needs Improvement"></iws:attr-option>
```

**Example 2:**

Original:

```
<source>
    <ph id="12" x="&lt;/span>">{12}</ph>
</source>
```

Data getting from Read(), notice the ">" symbol is replaced with "& gt;"

```
<source>
    <ph id="12" x="&lt;/span&gt;">{12}</ph>
</source>
```

**Example 3:**

I am not able to paste the code here as the special character is not even displaying here, so adding image.
left is the original and right side one is what i am getting in read(), special character is missing.

[image]

Code Sameple : (I am not sure if we can post code directly here)
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WWGE7fFJPKvs5KU5f_PlwWtoqCVxTcS0?usp=sharing

1. Above drive we have sample xml file and code.
2. "DevelopingADocumentBasedApp" is the code, just open the "DocumentBasedApp.xcodeproj", run it.
   3 .Once it runs, click on Menu->File->Open and open the provided xml file.
3. In content.swift, Keep a break point at "print(xmlDocument!)"
4. Here we can see the document is modified by NSDocument, and it is different from the original

---

**Edit:**

@matt Thank you for making me understand real problem, Initially i thought that i have issue with NSDocument's read(). But issues is XMLDocument() not returning exact data. I need to find a solution for that.

---

Comment: I don't think `NSDocument` is modifying the data. Are you sure you're opening and looking at the same file? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke , yes i am checking same file. I will give example code shortly.

Comment: Unrelated but when I see that: `XMLNode.Options(rawValue: XMLNode.Options.RawValue(Int(XMLNode.Options.nodePreserveWhitespace.rawValue)))`, shoudln't it be simplified with just `XMLNode.Options.nodePreserveWhitespace`?

Comment: @Willeke , Posted sample code in gdrive link. Please check and let me know if you have any issues accessing it.

Comment: @Larme Yes, you are correct. We can do it in a simple way ;) . Not sure why i did it but i will change it. This does not have any effect on the issue :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading is not changing your document.

You make an xml document, with `XMLDocument(data:...)`. You are asking for a new valid XML document based on your original, and that is exactly what you get. The resulting structure is *not* a big string, like your original data; it is an elaborate *node tree* reflecting the *structure* of your XML. That node tree is identical to the structure described by your original. That fact does not affect in any way your ability to parse the document; indeed, it is why you are *able* to parse the document. If you think it does cause an inability to parse the document, your parsing code is wrong (but you didn't show that, so no more can be said).

Also note that your evidence for what is "in" the XML document is indirect; the XML document is a node tree, but the strings you display are the output of a secondary *rendering* into a *string*. That rendering representation is arbitrary and malleable; it obeys its own rules of formatting. (And again, you didn't show anything about *how* you obtain that rendering. Perhaps we are talking about your `print` statement?)

The point is, you seem to have to some sort of expectation about how passing *into* an XMLDocument and then back *out* of it will "round trip" your original string in such a way that the output looks just like the original. That expectation is incorrect. That's not what XMLDocument does.

And merely reading the original `data` into an XMLDocument did *not* change the `data`, I can promise you that.

So don't worry, be happy; as far as the validity of your XML is concerned, everything is fine, and the data you started with has not been altered in any way.

---

Here's a demonstration:

```
let xmlstring = """
<testing>
<fun whatever="thingy" />
</testing>
"""
print(xmlstring)
let xmldata = xmlstring.data(using: .utf8)!
let xml = try? XMLDocument(data: xmldata, options: [])
print("=======")
print(xml!)
```

The output is:

```
<testing>
<fun whatever="thingy" />
</testing>
=======
<?xml version="1.0"?><testing><fun whatever="thingy"></fun></testing>
```

As you can see, the output from the `print` is not the same as the input string. But it *is* a valid XML representation of the original string, and that's all that matters. And the original `xmlstring` and `xmldata` that I started with are, I assure you, completely untouched.

Comment: Problem here is when i save back the document it is saving the new version. But I want to save only edited part not complete document.

Comment: But none of _that_ is in your question. I have answered the question you asked. Don't blame me just because _you_ asked the wrong question.

Comment: Sorry not sure why you sound so angry, but please excuse my mistake. I am a small developer just trying to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: But the point is that what you are complaining about is not due to how you read the document but how you _write_ it. And your question gives no information about that. And even if you did, you simply cannot expect identical formatting to the original, as formatting is irrelevant to xml.

Comment: I am not sure what i did wrong but my English is not good and i may have not explained my problem correctly. Back story is we download a file from server, process it in my app do some changes and upload it back to server. In the xml/xlf file if there's any change in source element it rejects the file. Since NSDocument is altering the closing tags or symbols we are having difficulty in uploading back to server.

Comment: That's an interesting problem, to which the solution would probably be not to use XMLDocument at all, because it is not expected to "round trip" in the way you seem to require. But, again, that is _not what you asked_. You didn't mention _any_ of that in your question. So it is not up for discussion now. — Do you know what an xy question is?  https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I presume you would simply have to parse and modify the string that comes from the server _as a string_. (Perhaps regular expressions would help.) or perhaps the server is to blame. But the real way to get that question answered is to ask it (as a question). You didn't. I answered the question you _did_ ask.

Comment: That's totally fine, but I assure you, you are _not_ having issues with `read()`. You will not understand what you _are_ having issues with until you listen to what I'm telling you (or at least your would need to understand better what XML is and what XMLDocument does; you do not have to listen to _my_ explanation of them, but you need to get _some_ explanation of them into your understanding).

Comment: But Data i am getting from it is altered (i think so)as i mentioned in my question. I will try to parse in other ways and see if it helps.

Comment: It is unclear from your question why you are parsing your document into an XMLDocument at all. But the point is, merely doing that does not change the original document. If you _output_ the XMLDocument into a _new_ string, that _can_ be different, and that is _expected_, as my answer tells you.

Comment: For example, you say you are going to `print(xmlDocument!)`. But the output of that is not _expected_ to be the same as the `data` that you read from in `read`. I assure you that the `data` you read from has _not been affected_ by what you did.

Comment: I added code that proves all this.

Comment: One more point: if you think that NSDocument `read` can change the document as stored on disk, that's a mistake too. If the document stored on disk changes, that is because of your implementation of `data(ofType...)`. But you didn't show that in your question _either,_ so I have no idea what you are doing in that code.

Comment: thank you for your patience and you made me to understand the real problem (classic case of XYProblem ;) ). I cross checked the data from read() like : String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) , this gave me exact output like original document. I need to find a solution for my problem in another way. I think i will post different question. Thank you again.